# A Codility test that needs to be solved

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I can not understand the question, can someone clarify it a little bit ?

Update : here is my solution using Kadane algorithm but it fails at the following arrays:

```
Example test:    [-8, 3, 0, 5, -3, 12] 
WRONG ANSWER  (got 17 expected 12) 

Example test:    [-1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, -3, 4, 3, 0, -1] 
WRONG ANSWER  (got 12 expected 8) 

int max_so_far = 0, max_ending_here = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
    {
        max_ending_here = max_ending_here + A[i];
        if (max_ending_here < 0)
            max_ending_here = 0;
        if (max_so_far < max_ending_here)
            max_so_far = max_ending_here;
    }
    return max_so_far;
```

Comment: Dumping an assignment and saying "I don't understand" does not make for an acceptable question.

Comment: @CodyGray Can you explain it to me in clear english,I dont know is slice (3,4). from where it get it.

Comment: @andre  The example of an array is incorrect because the element with index 3 is absent.:)

Comment: I assume that non negative slice stands for a non negative sum of a slice. Then you have to test the sum of each slice in order to find the maximum.

Comment: @Polux66 Or non-negative elements of an array?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I fixed it

Comment: @andre Why is slice (0, 1) absent?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow sorry I missed that. can you elaborate a solution

Comment: @andre So is slice is a subsequence of non-negative elements of an array?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yes its non negative elements of an array

Comment: I have updated my code and wrote a solution but it doesnt accept all the test cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function can look as it is shown in the demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

long long int solution( const std::vector<int> &v )
{
    long long int max_sum = 0;

    for ( auto it = v.begin(); 
         ( it = std::find_if( it, v.end(), []( int x ) { return !( x < 0 ); } ) ) != v.end(); 
        )
    {
        long long int sum = 0;

        while ( it != v.end() && !( *it < 0 ) ) sum += *it++;

        if ( max_sum < sum ) max_sum = sum;
    }

    return max_sum;
}   


int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, -3, 4, 5, -6 };

    std::cout << solution( v ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
9
```

You can rewrite the function using indices instead of iterators.

As for your function then it is incorrect at least relative to this condition

```
    if (max_ending_here < 0)
        max_ending_here = 0;
```

because instead of checking the current element whether it is less than zero the condition checks the current sum of elements.

Comment: I want to know the error in my algorithm, the code that I used